# how can I get value "2002-2-28" in this format, from "Feb 28 2002", in react datepicker

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, date-format

I am using react datepicker and when I catch value in onchange it gives me "Thu Feb 28 2002 11:34:59 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time)" this type value but I simply want "2002-2-28" this output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a handleDate function that converts date to your desired format.

```
App() {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());

  const handleDate = (date) => {
    const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    const day = date.getDate();
    setStartDate(`${year}-${month}-${day}`);
  };

  return (
    <DatePicker
      showPopperArrow={false}
      selected={new Date(startDate)}
      onChange={(date) => handleDate(date)}
    />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below function, to which you can pass the format you are getting from date picker and it will return you the desired value. I have added 1 to month since the month value comes from (0-11)

```
  export function getFormat(value) {
        let date = new Date(value);
        var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
        var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
        var day = date.getDay();
        return  yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + day
    }
```

Comment: Could you please upvote and accept the answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `moment` library like so:

```
import moment from 'moment'
// ...
moment("Thu Feb 28 2002 11:34:59 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time)").format("YYYY-M-DD")
```

Also you can use any other format.

[Documentation here](https://momentjs.com/docs/)